# Application of Leibniz rule when derivative tends to infinity

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory

Consider the CDF $F(x)$, for $x\in[0,1]$ and the integral, for $n\geq 1$,

$$I(x,n)=\int_0^1[F(x)]^ndx.$$

I am interested in computing $\frac{\partial I(x,n)}{\partial n}$, and I'm trying to use the Leibniz rule, namely, bringing the derivative operator inside the integral—or MCT/DCT for that matter. However, I am not sure I can use the Leibniz rule because $\frac{\partial [F(x)]^n}{\partial n}=[F(x)]^n\log(F(x))$, which is exists and is continuous in $x$ for all $x\in(0,1]$, but for $x=0$, $\frac{\partial [F(x)]^n}{\partial n}$ is of the form $-\infty\cdot 0$. Arbitrarily setting $-\infty\cdot 0$ might kill the continuity of $\frac{\partial [F(x)]^n}{\partial n}$ if $[F(x)]^n\log(F(x))\to-\infty$ as $x\to 0$, eliminating my hope of using Leibniz Rule. **Should I ask additional things from $F(x)$ to make Leibniz rule work? or I'm missing something and it works with the setup I have? If the problem can be solved by applying MCT/DCT, I am happy with that too.**

I know that for $F(x)=x$, the uniform distribution, things work:

$$I(x,n)=\int_0^1x^ndx=\frac{1}{n+1}\Rightarrow \frac{\partial I(x,n)}{\partial n}=-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}, $$
and
$$\int_0^1\frac{\partial x^n}{\partial n}dx=\int_0^1\log(x)x^ndx=\log(x)x^n\bigg|_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{n+1}dx=-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}.$$

Where the last inequality follows from $\log(x)x^n\to 0$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: $\frac{\partial [F(x)]^n}{\partial n}=[F(x)]^n\log(x)$ is not correct, though that does not solve your problem.

Comment: A question you should ask yourself is "what is $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac {d 0^n}{dn}?"$$